# YouTube in database. Markdown

Tags: markdown

I have a blog. I store the body of each post in a database. I use PHP and MySql. I write that text in the database in Markdown. I do not use any parser or flavour, I write the markdown just with the basic rules of John Gruber: [link to Gruber site](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#im).
When I output that I use regex to transform it to html. It works well. But now I have a YouTube Video in the middle of the body of the text. I am not sure how to write it in markdown. If I understand what John Gruber says, there is no rule for that, then I should write it in plain html. But I think It would not be correct to store an iframe code in the database. Am I right? If so, how should I store an iFrame YouTube video in the database?. For instance:

```
## This is a subtitle

This is a paragraph

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9IBLg4gCXiQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

This is another paragraph
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing HTML code in the database is perfectly fine. (Why shouldn't it be? Writing your own markdown parser based on regexes is another matter though...)

If you trust all the people writing markdown/html you don't even need to sanitize it for allowed HTML tags.

Comment: I am the only one that write the markdown in that database. I understand that I can put html in the database but I have been searching here in Stackoverflow and in other places and there are people that say that is not a good practice.

Comment: don't think so. can you point to a specific SO answer that says so? All the major CMS (wordpress, drupal etc.) do this btw... and yes, as I mentioned, if you have users inputting html it makes sense to keep only allowed tags (and strip e.g. `<script>` etc.)